# Drag and Drop of a map in widows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps, bing-api

I am building a windows phone 8 using BingMapsDirectionsTask

```
BingMapsDirectionsTask task = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();


ShowMyLocationOnTheMap();

LabeledMapLocation start = new LabeledMapLocation(myCrntAddres, new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate());
LabeledMapLocation end = new LabeledMapLocation(desLoc.Text, new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate());
task.Start = start;
task.End = end;
```

The code is working fine, but I want to add functionality so that a user can drag route on map which is already mapped between user current location and user inputed
address.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality isn't built-in and isn't supported by BingMapsDirectionsTask/MapsDirectionsTask.

If you want this functionality you'll have to build it into your own app using the new WP8 `<Map />` control instead of using a Launcher. Read more about the new Map control @ http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!guide-to-the-maps.html;#toc_Mapcontrol